# Compile error while trying to open a file using Dr.Java

Tags: java

So I am currently taking an intro to java course in college, and so far I have been successful at figuring out and solving the problems. Until now. I am having some kind of compiling error when I am trying to open and read a file. I was following my class textbook with its set instructions for the base code to do this and it ended in error. I then took the source code from my book and put that into Dr.Java and it still compiled in error and that was from the book. So I am not exactly sure what the problem is and was wondering if someone could lead me in the right direction. F.Y.I. it is always the same two errors. Thank you.

```
import java.util.Scanner; // Needed for the Scanner class
import java.io.*;         // Needed for the File class

/**
   This program reads data from a file.
*/

public class FileReadDemo
{
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
   {
      // Create a Scanner object for keyboard input.
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

      // Get the filename.
      System.out.print("Enter the filename: ");
      String filename = keyboard.nextLine();

      // Open the file.
      File file = new File(filename);
      Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);

      // Read lines from the file until no more are left.
      while (inputFile.hasNext())
      {
         // Read the next name.
         String friendName = inputFile.nextLine();

         // Display the last name read.
         System.out.println(friendName);
      }

      // Close the file.
      inputFile.close();
   }
}
```

Here is the error codes that keep occurring.

2 errors found:

```
File: C:\Users\aspea\Documents\Intro to Computers and Java\FileReadDemo.java  [line: 20]
Error: constructor File in class File cannot be applied to given types;
  required: no arguments
  found: java.lang.String
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

File: C:\Users\aspea\Documents\Intro to Computers and Java\FileReadDemo.java  
[line: 21]
Error: no suitable constructor found for Scanner(File)
    constructor java.util.Scanner.Scanner(java.lang.Readable) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; File cannot be converted to java.lang.Readable)
    constructor java.util.Scanner.Scanner(java.io.InputStream) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; File cannot be converted to java.io.InputStream)
    constructor java.util.Scanner.Scanner(java.io.File) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; File cannot be converted to java.io.File)
    constructor java.util.Scanner.Scanner(java.nio.file.Path) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; File cannot be converted to java.nio.file.Path)
    constructor java.util.Scanner.Scanner(java.lang.String) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; File cannot be converted to java.lang.String)
    constructor java.util.Scanner.Scanner(java.nio.channels.ReadableByteChannel) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; File cannot be converted to java.nio.channels.ReadableByteChannel)
```

Comment: I am very sure I copied and pasted. I think something else is wrong but I am not to sure.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have some custom `File` class which is not `java.io.File`, the following errors indicate that fact :

```
Error: constructor File in class File cannot be applied to given types;
  required: no arguments
  found: java.lang.String
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

And

```
File cannot be converted to java.io.File
```

Comment: So what do you recommend I do. I am not sure where to go.

Comment: Nevermind I just deleted a file named file. Probably not the best idea then all of a sudden it worked thank you so much.